# 3 Ants going at different speeds, when they will be at the same place Motion Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The circumference of a circle has length 90 centimeters, Three points on the circle divide the circle into three equal lengths. Three ants A, B, and C start to crawl clockwise on the circle, with starting from one of the three points. Initially A is ahead of B and B is ahead of C. Ant A crawls 3 centimeters per second, ant V 5 centimeters, and and C 10 centimeters. How long does it take for the three ants to arrive at the same spot for the first time?

I tried making a list and writing down the numbers, but they seem to never be the same. I know the distance formula is *d=rt*, but I don't know how to use it to solve this problem. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**.  Suppose that the ants meet after $t$ seconds, and measure distance around the circle from where C starts.  Then A has travelled $3t$ metres, but had a $60$ metre start for a total of $60+3t$ from the initial point.  Likewise B will be a distance 30+5t from the initial point.  However B may have travelled a number of times around the circle, say $x$ times more than A, and therefore has travelled $90x$ metres further than A.  So we have the equation
$$60+3t+90x=30+5t\ .$$
See if you can explain by using similar ideas why
$$60+3t+90y=10t\ ,$$
where $y$ is the number of times C has "lapped" A.

Now eliminate $t$ from these two equations; then find the smallest possible values of $x$ and $y$, remembering that while $t$ could be any positive number, $x$ and $y$ must be positive integers.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

At the start, C is at location 0, B is at location 30 and A is at location 60. It is easy to see that C will catch up to B in 6 seconds at location 60. And then they will meet again at location 60 every 18 seconds after that. When will A be at location 60? Well, he starts out there and he gets back there every 30 seconds.

So, B and C will be at the right place in 6, 24, 42, 60, 78 etc. seconds while A will be at the right place in 30, 60, 90 etc. seconds. We now see that they meet for the first time after **60 seconds**.

To help verify that this is correct you can see that 0 + 10 * 60 = 600; 30 + 5 * 60 = 330; 60 + 3 * 60 = 240. It is easy to see that 600, 330 and 240 all refer to the same spot on the circle. Formally expressed 600 mod 90 = 330 mod 90 = 240 mod 90 = 60.

Answer (score 2):

First focus on A and B.  Since B goes 2 cm/sec faster than A, B first catches A after 15 seconds; and then every 45 seconds thereafter.

Now look at B and C.  Since C goes 5 cm/sec faster than B, C first catches B after 6 seconds, and every 18 seconds there after.

So A and B coincide at times $15 + 45n$ seconds for $n = 0, 1, ...$; and B and C coincide at times $6 + 18k$ seconds for $k = 0, 1, 2,...$.

So you need $15 + 45n=6 + 18k$ for nonnegative integer $n,k$.

The smallest solution is $n=1, k=3$.  Giving a time of $60$ seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, without affecting the result of the problem, that ant $A$ starts at the polar coordinates of angle $0$ on the unit circle, the other ants will be at position $2\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $4\frac{\pi }{3}$.
Let's try to find three functions, $f$, $g$, $h$, that takes $t$ (time) as argument, and yields the angle at which ant $A$, $B$, and $C$ will be at the given $t$ moment, respectively.
Since the speed is constant, the three functions will be linear.

We know that:

$f(0)=0$

Since the ant $A$ will walk $3$($\frac{90}{30}$) centimeters in $1$ second, it will walk $\frac{1}{30}$ of the circle in $1$ second, so the new angle will decrease by $2\frac{ \pi}{30}$.

$f(1)=-\frac{\pi}{15}$

$f(t)=at+b$

$f(0)=b=0$

$f(1)=a=-\frac{\pi}{15}=>a=-\frac{\pi}{15}$

Similarly, we can compute for $g$ and $h$.

$f(t)=-\frac{\pi}{15}t$

$g(t)=-\frac{\pi}{9}t+2\frac{\pi}{3}$

$h(t)=-2\frac{\pi}{9}t+4\frac{\pi}{3}$

Now, it only remains to solve the equation(for any $n$, $m$).

$f(t)=g(t)+2n\pi =h(t)+2m\pi $

Comment: Expressing the position by the angle doesn't make anything simpler and fills your calculation with fractions of $\pi$, making it more likely that you'll make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of simplifying the problem:

A is at 4 o'clock, B is at 12 o'clock, and C is at 8 o'clock.

Let's subtract $5$ cm/s from each ant's speed.  So now C is going clockwise at only $5$ cm/s, B is stationary, and A is going **counter-clockwise** at $2$ cm/s.  And they're all still $30$ cm apart. Subtracting the same amount from each ant's speed doesn't change the solution to the problem: in physics terms, it's equivalent to working in ant B's frame of reference, instead of the circle's.

C will reach B after $\frac{30}{5}$ sec, and thereafter every  $\frac{90}{5}$ sec, or after $6, 24, 42, 60, 78$, ... seconds

A will reach B after $\frac{30}{2}$ sec, and thereafter every  $\frac{90}{2}$ sec, or after $15, 60, 105$, ... seconds

The first double hit is after 60 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the angle as the ant's position indicator. Note that $$\theta  = \frac{s}{r} = \frac{s}{{\frac{{90}}{{2\pi }}}} = \frac{{2\pi s}}{{90}}$$Now:$$\begin{array}{l}{\theta _{\rm{A}}}(t) = {\omega _{\rm{A}}}t + {\theta _{{{\rm{A}}_0}}}\\{\theta _{\rm{B}}}(t) = {\omega _{\rm{B}}}t + {\theta _{{{\rm{B}}_0}}}\\{\theta _{\rm{C}}}(t) = {\omega _{\rm{C}}}t + {\theta _{{{\rm{C}}_0}}}\end{array}$$and$$\begin{array}{l}{\theta _{{{\rm{A}}_0}}} =  - \frac{{4\pi }}{3}\\{\theta _{{{\rm{B}}_0}}} =  - \frac{{2\pi }}{3}\\{\theta _{{{\rm{C}}_0}}} = 0\end{array}$$where$$\begin{array}{l}{\omega _{\rm{A}}} = \frac{{6\pi }}{{90}}\\{\omega _{\rm{B}}} = \frac{{10\pi }}{{90}}\\{\omega _{\rm{C}}} = \frac{{20\pi }}{{90}}\end{array}$$Your question could be re-written as find a $t$ such that$$\begin{array}{l}{\theta _{\rm{C}}}(t) - {\theta _{\rm{B}}}(t)\mathop  \equiv \limits^{2\pi } 0\\{\theta _{\rm{C}}}(t) - {\theta _{\rm{A}}}(t)\mathop  \equiv \limits^{2\pi } 0\end{array}$$Replacing the data and simplifying yields$$\begin{array}{l}\frac{{\pi t + 6\pi }}{9}\mathop  \equiv \limits^{2\pi } 0\\\frac{{7\pi t + 60\pi}}{{45}}\mathop  \equiv \limits^{2\pi } 0\end{array}$$ which is equivalent to $$\begin{array}{l}t + 6\mathop  \equiv \limits^{18} 0\\7t + 60\mathop  \equiv \limits^{90} 0\end{array}$$Combining the second equation with the first, yields $$\begin{array}{l}t\mathop  \equiv \limits^{18} 12\\t\mathop  \equiv \limits^{30} 0\end{array}$$The first solution to these is $t=30$.

Comment: That makes it seems harder though...what's the the greek alphavet for? I still gave an upvote for answering though.

Comment: Expressing the position by the angle doesn't make anything simpler and fills your calculation with fractions of $\pi$, making it more likely that you'll make mistakes.

Comment: @Anonymous Using $\theta$ for an angle and $\omega$ for an angular velocity is as standard as using $t$ for time or $r$ for radius.